# php mail with .js validation -> can't see any mistakes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got this piece of code from a free template and I followed all the instructions that came with it, everything seems fine but mail doesn't go trough.
HTML:

```
                <!--Start Contact form -->                                                      
<form name="enq" method="post" action="email/" onsubmit="return validation();">
  <fieldset>

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  class="input-block-level" placeholder="Name.." />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email.." />
    <textarea rows="11" name="message" id="message" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Message.."></textarea>
    <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Send!" name="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-info pull-right" title="Send!" />
    </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>                  
            <!--End Contact form -->
```

PHP

```
    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="email@sample.com";
 $subject="Enquiry!";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         Name:
         $name     
         <br>
         Email-Id:
         $email        
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission! Thankyou for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
        //contact:-your-email@your-domain.com
 }
?>
```

JavaScript

```
 function validation()
 {

    var contactname=document.enq.name.value;
    var name_exp=/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
    if(contactname=='')
    {
        alert("Name Field Should Not Be Empty!");
        document.enq.name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!contactname.match(name_exp))
    {
        alert("Invalid Name field!");
        document.enq.name.focus();
        return false;
    }

    var email=document.enq.email.value;
    //var email_exp=/^[A-Za-z0-9\.-_\$]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    var email_exp=/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
    if(email=='')
    {
        alert("Please Enter Email-Id!");
        document.enq.email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(!email.match(email_exp))
    {
        alert("Invalid Email ID !");
        document.enq.email.focus();
        return false;
    }


    var message=document.enq.message.value;
    if(message=='')
    {
        alert("Query Field Should Not Be Empty!");
        document.enq.message.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

I don't get any errors but mail doesn't simply go trough, checked spam etc.

Comment: Does all this code appear in the same page?

Comment: Nope. 3 separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you changed

```
$to="email@sample.com";
```

to your actual e-mail.. I can't see anything else.

Comment: Yeah. Confused also, trying to figure out this for a while now, decided to post for some help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was due to webhost(mailserver). Works like a charm on another webhost.